# SOAPAction header on Outgoing message with WebHttpBinding

Tags: wcf

I tried to emit an http header but somehow wcf filters it.

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IHelloWorld
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "*", IsOneWay = false, ReplyAction = "*")]
    void Hello(string text);
}

        var channel = new ChannelFactory<IHelloWorld>(new WebHttpBinding(), "http://some.where");
        channel.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        var proxy = channel.CreateChannel();
        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy))
        {
            MessageProperties messageProperties = OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties;

            var requestMessageProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            messageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, requestMessageProperty);

            requestMessageProperty.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "test");
            requestMessageProperty.Headers.Add("Test", "test2");

            proxy.Hello("test");
        }
```

When testing this code, the header Test is in the request but SOAPAction is not.
I tried with a IClientMessageInspector but it doesn't work either.
I cannot use another binding (Basic or a more Soap dedicated one).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the SOAPAction field is the HTTP header default field and is used to indicate that the action method being invoked when server service uses a non-webhttpbinding.
I don't think it could be arbitrarily specified by intercepting the message/operation context.
[image]